# Extracting a value from json and using as a key in new dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a Json file and want to extract some information from it into a new dict.

The json looks something like this:

```
{
    "code": "C568219u",
    },
    "body_text": [
        {
            "text": "some text",
            "other_item": "3fd"
            }
            {
            "text": "more text"
            }
            ]
}
```

I want to get the "code" - which is the issue- as a key in my new dict, and the text as the value.

The dict would ideally look like this:

```
{C568219u:"all the text"}
```

For extracting the text it worked like this:

```
with open("C:\\root\test.json", 'r') as content:
            try:
                temp = []
                json_file = json.load(content)
                for item in json_file["body_text"]:
                    temp.append(item["text"]) 
                    text = " ".join(f)
            except:
                print(":(")
  

print(text)
```

But now extracting the "code" and setting it as the key, and then updating the dict won't work with my code.

Which looks like this so far:

```
full_text= {}
with open("C:\\root\test.json", 'r') as content:
            try:
                json_file = json.load(content)
                temp = []
                if 'code' in content:
                    c_id = content['code']    
               
                    for item in json_file["body_text"]:
                        temp.append(item["text"])   
                        text = " ".join(temp)
                        full.update[c_id:text]
                    
            except:
                print(":(")
```

Any ideas on what the issue might be and how to reach my goal?

Comment: `if 'code' in content:` Presumably you meant to say `if 'code' in json_file:` instead.

Comment: Also, that's a _terrible_ way of handling exceptions.  You're deliberately hiding the actual error, which means you will have absolutely no idea what actually went wrong.

Comment: @JohnGordon It tried changing it, didn't make a difference. As for the exceptions, it ran the code without the try/except and it didn't throw an error, but also didn't work.

Comment: Your example tries too hard to help us, but instead makes it worse. What is "all the text"? Don't tell us to get all the text, tell us exactly what all the text should be for that example. Should it be "some text more text"?

Comment: This seems to work fine, after I fix all the json errors and obvious python errors. I'd recommend you just debug your code. DO NOT suppress the exceptions -- let them halt your program and tell you what to fix. Then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the ideal way to do it, but I changed my code to:

```
full_text= {}
with open("C:\\root\test.json", 'r') as content:
            try:
                json_file = json.load(content)
                temp = []
                for item in json_file:
                    c_id = content['code']    
               
                    for item in json_file["body_text"]:
                        temp.append(item["text"])   
                        text = " ".join(temp)
                        almost = {c_id:text}
                        full.update(almost)
                    
            except:
                print(":(")
```

And it worked.

Still don't really understand json-files, but this way it came out the way I wanted it to!
Yeah!!